# Mean number of offsprings at time n

Tags: probability, expected-value

> Definition for expected value: $\mu= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kp_{k}$

In a text, the author mentioned that

> for a time n-1 where the offspring is $X_{n-1}=m$, the mean number of offsprings at time n is $m\mu$

Would someone give me why this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

Let the number of offspring by the $i$-th offspring in the $(n-1)$-th generation be $Y_i$ where $i \in \{1,\ldots, m\}$.

Then the number of offspring in the $n$-th generation is $\sum_{i=1}^m Y_i$.

Compute it's mean by using linearity of expectation. Can you complete the task?

Comment: I do not have a background in probability but I'm familiar with the linearity principle so it does look doable.

Comment: layman terms: You have exactly $1$ sibling and each of you are expected to have $3$ kids each. how many grandson do your parents  expect to have

Comment: The expected number of grandsons to exist is six.

Comment: the working is the same. just more algebra =)

Comment: In your third line, should we replace "individual" in "Then the number of individual in the n-th..." with "off springs"?

Comment: sure, thanks. I have changed individual to offsprings.

Comment: Also, number of offsprings in the (n-1)-th generation.

Comment: Hmmm... the next generation comes from current generation. If we were to describe the current generation as "offsprings", then I think I have to used "offsprings of offsprings"?

Comment: I didn't realise you edited the 2nd sentence. Now, "n-th generation" makes sense.